# big file upload through web portal

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a web portal (Laravel PHP); one of its functions is to let user upload files as big as a few GB through HTTPS. Some users may have slow Internet speed.

I've come across tus.io, which seems able to meet my big size requirement. However, tus.io is based on HTTP protocol; I cannot find any of its example in HTTPS.

I have read some article about using Apache to redirect HTTPS traffic to HTTP, meaning I run a tus HTTP server behind Apache, which can take HTTPS traffic and redirect to tus HTTP server. But how about the browser/client side?

I also wonder what are the technologies used by google drive and Dropbox. If they use open source, I may also consider to adopt in my project.

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/free-open-source-cloud-storage-tools-for-linux/